# Username and password doesn't work (BASIC AUTH)

Tags: apache-2.2

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "staging"
AuthUserFile "/etc/httpd/pass/password"
require valid-user
```

I see this and inside /etc/httpd/pass/password

I see

```
example1:justanexample
example2:dasd
example3:notatruepass
```

and none of these credentials works when Apache request an username and password.

Comment: Could you look at the Apache logs if something is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/auth.html), try to generate your password file with :

```sh
# Delete plain text password file
rm /etc/httpd/pass/password
# Generate first user
htpasswd -c /etc/httpd/pass/password example1
# Type a password
# Do it again
htpasswd -c /etc/httpd/pass/password example2
htpasswd -c /etc/httpd/pass/password example3
```